# how to use osticket API Key

Tags: php, osticket

I have generated an API key from osticket (v.1.10) admin panel and set my IP to 127.0.0.1, and I have downloaded the this php script but I don't know the path to save this document and what the URL should be (is it my admin panel URL or else?) and how can I test it?

```html
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
#
# Configuration: Enter the url and key. That is it.
#  url => URL to api/task/cron e.g #  http://yourdomain.com/support/api/tickets.json
#  key => API's Key (see admin panel on how to generate a key)
#  $data add custom required fields to the array.
#
#  Originally authored by jared@osTicket.com
#  Modified by ntozier@osTicket / tmib.net

// If 1, display things to debug.
$debug="0";

// You must configure the url and key in the array below.

$config = array(
        'url'=>'http://site.tld/api/tickets.json',  // URL to site.tld/api/tickets.json
      'key'=>'27ADED3FED6AC18D8068FCB942DB4442'  // API Key goes here
);
# NOTE: some people have reported having to use "http://your.domain.tld/api/http.php/tickets.json" instead.

if($config['url'] === 'http://site.tld/api/tickets.json') {
  echo "<p style=\"color:red;\"><b>Error: No URL</b><br>You have not configured this script with your URL!</p>";
  echo "Please edit this file ".__FILE__." and add your URL at line 18.</p>";
  die();  
}  
if(IsNullOrEmptyString($config['key']) || ($config['key'] === '27ADED3FED6AC18D8068FCB942DB4442'))  {
  echo "<p style=\"color:red;\"><b>Error: No API Key</b><br>You have not configured this script with an API Key!</p>";
  echo "<p>Please log into osticket as an admin and navigate to: Admin panel -> Manage -> Api Keys then add a new API Key.<br>";
  echo "Once you have your key edit this file ".__FILE__." and add the key at line 19.</p>";
  die();
}
  
# Fill in the data for the new ticket, this will likely come from $_POST.
# NOTE: your variable names in osT are case sensiTive. 
# So when adding custom lists or fields make sure you use the same case
# For examples on how to do that see Agency and Site below.
$data = array(
    'name'      =>      'John Doe',  // from name aka User/Client Name
    'email'     =>      'john@gmail.com',  // from email aka User/Client Email
    'phone'    =>    '1234567890',  // phone number aka User/Client Phone Number
    'subject'   =>      'Test API message',  // test subject, aka Issue Summary
    'message'   =>      'This is a test of the osTicket API',  // test ticket body, aka Issue Details.
    'ip'        =>      $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], // Should be IP address of the machine thats trying to open the ticket.
   'topicId'   =>      '1', // the help Topic that you want to use for the ticket 
 //'Agency'  =>  '58', //this is an example of a custom list entry. This should be the number of the entry.
 //'Site' =>  'Bermuda'; // this is an example of a custom text field.  You can push anything into here you want. 
    'attachments' => array()
);

# more fields are available and are documented at:
# https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket-1.8/blob/develop/setup/doc/api/tickets.md

if($debug=='1') {
  print_r($data);
  die();
}

# Add in attachments here if necessary
# Note: there is something with this wrong with the file attachment here it does not work.
$data['attachments'][] =
array('file.txt' =>
        'data:text/plain;base64;'
            .base64_encode(file_get_contents('/file.txt')));  // replace ./file.txt with /path/to/your/test/filename.txt
 

#pre-checks
function_exists('curl_version') or die('CURL support required');
function_exists('json_encode') or die('JSON support required');

#set timeout
set_time_limit(30);

#curl post
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $config['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'osTicket API Client v1.8');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Expect:', 'X-API-Key: '.$config['key']));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if ($code != 201)
    die('Unable to create ticket: '.$result);

$ticket_id = (int) $result;

# Continue onward here if necessary. $ticket_id has the ID number of the
# newly-created ticket

function IsNullOrEmptyString($question){
    return (!isset($question) || trim($question)==='');
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: so did you edit `http://site.tld/api/tickets.json` ?

Comment: i didn't edit anything, except the `api key` part. I don't know what `site.tld` should be, is it refer to osticket admin panel or else? @Scuzzy

Comment: I would assume it should be your domian/path. Look at the code `if($config['url'] === 'http://site.tld/api/tickets.json') {` its testing if you've changed this or not.

Comment: i have saved it in my `xampp/htdocs` root folder, change the url to `localhost/api/tickets.json` and try to access it `localhost/ost-api-example.php` but its not working :) @Scuzzy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I just have to change the URL and KEY inside `$config=array()`. And if you have the same problem as me trying to test new ticket from API on `localhost`, all you need to do is change the URL to `http://127.0.0.1/yourosticketsite/api/http.php/tickets.json` .